# Choosing method implementation at runtime

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'd like to configure the behaviour of objects at runtime by choosing a method to call out of a given set. Consider this simple example:

```
class Parameter;

class Conf;

class Obj {
public:
    Obj( const Conf &t ): t_( t ) {}
    void f( Parameter *d );
    void f1( Parameter *d );
    void f2( Parameter *d );
    typedef void ( Obj::*Fn )( Parameter *d );
private:
    const Conf &t_;
};

class Conf {
public:
    Obj::Fn f;
};

void Obj::f( Parameter *d ) {
    ( this->*t_.f )( d );
}
```

By changing `Conf::f` for a given `Conf` object, the behaviour of all `Obj` objects configured with this is changed.

First question: Does this resemble some design pattern (ok, it's kind of a method-pointer-strategy-thing...)? If so, should I consider a redesign?

Second question: I'd like to make this more flexible by using different parameter classes. I've already done this by making `Parameter` a base class and doing type casting in the `fN` methods, but that does not look like a final solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Strategy Pattern may work here.

Comment: Regarding your parameter issue, make Obj or Parameter a template type?

Comment: Consider using std::function<> instead of method pointer.

Comment: @verbose-mode The methods `f1()` and `f2()` modify the internal state of the object. Is the strategy pattern applicable in this case?

Comment: @Spook You mean replacing the `typedef` with the declaration of `boost::function< void ( Obj*, Parameter* ) > f;` (im still C++03 here)? What is the benefit?

Comment: Not sure but in C# this seems like dependency injection for me

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), considering when the state changes, a method will be called on a different object. If you look at the Java example of the wikipedia link, the StateContext object has the myState attribute which will be changed to a different State object for state changes.

You could do something similar, whereby your Obj class would have a pointer/reference to an object that implements a method specified in the interface that it implements. Then the internal pointer/reference could be changed to point to a different object, either by internal logic or by setting it externally, and then the method being called will be different.

Here is a brief example:

```
class Action
{
    virtual void action() = 0;
}

class Action1 : public Action
{
    virtual void action() { /* do something useful here */ }
};

class Action2 : public Action
{
    virtual void action() { /* do something different here */ }
}

class Obj
{
public:
    setAction(Action *a) {a_ = a;}
    void action() {if(a_) a_->action();}
private:
    Action *a_;
};

{
    Action1 a1;
    Action2 a2;
    Obj o;
    o.setAction(&a1);
    o.action();

    o.setAction(&a2);
    o.action();
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this is also very similar to the Strategy pattern.

Comment: Does this have any advantage over passing a function object (with overloaded operator() ) as a template parameter?

Comment: @nurettin, good question, I guess it boils down to the difference/preference between templates and inheritance, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: As I said in a comment to the question, the actions should be able to modify the internal state of the object (as methods can do). You can't really do that in `/* do something useful here */`.